# pandas extra a new header from a already exist header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = DataFrame({'DATE' : ['2017-01-01','2017-01-02'],'Sexuality/us' :['femle','male'],'Height/us' :[190,195]})

     DATE        Sexuality/us   Height/us  
0  2017-01-01        female         190   
1  2017-01-02        male           195
```

1. As you see this is a pandas DataFrame data
2. I want to transfer this DataFrame to csv
3. When I use df.to_csv('demo.csv') as blow

   > [image: the csv screenshot]
4. What I really want to get is like this(extract the `us` to another row, of course, there may be many countries, I want to extract countries to an row as header):

   > [image: final result I need]
5. Any one can help me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put `DATE` into the index then you can split your columns by `/` and create a multiindex.

```
df = df.set_index('DATE')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('/', expand=True)
df.reset_index().swaplevel(axis=1)

                  us          
         DATE Height Sexuality
0  2017-01-01    190     femle
1  2017-01-02    195      male
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a lot.

Comment: @gesanghuayuan if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the chosen answer.